# Android won't call onResume()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onresume, activity-lifecycle

I have the following problem:

- I have `Activity1` and `Activity2`.
- I start `Activity2` from `Activity1`.
- `Activity1.onPause()` is called.
- `Activity2` finishes and closes and `Activity1` restarts. When this happens, nothing is called for `Activity1` - neither `onResume()`, nor `onCreate()`, nor `onStart()`.

What should I do? I really need `onResume()`.

Comment: Can we see some code because generally in such cases onCreate() or onStart() should not be called for Activity1 but onResume() should be called once the activity becomes visible again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You tried to work with `onCreate()` on restart - this won't work. See important details on the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to get used to its functions.

Next, since `onResume()` and `onStart()` should work fine according to the Activity lifecycle, make sure your code is valid and contains no bugs.

---

However, you could try to call `onRestart()`, too. This is the best place to insert code which should only be executed if the `Activity` restarts.